# 301 Redirect CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, web

I've recently started a new job and I noticed that a page linked to in one of our mailing lists no longer exists. I'm a developer / sysadmin so I thought it would be simple to set up a redirect, however our site is running CakePHP on the backend which I've got no experience with.

I want to redirect `oursite.com/page/online-store` to just `oursite.com`

I've tried `Router::redirect('/page/online-store', 'http://www.oursite.com', array('status' => 301));` at the bottom of that file but it doesn't seem to be working, it just hangs at page load until I comment that line out.

Relevant lines in routes.php:

```
// login and register
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'accounts', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/register', array('controller' => 'accounts', 'action' => 'register'));

// home
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'site', 'action' => 'home'));
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => true));

// dashboard
Router::connect('/admin/dashboard', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'dashboard', 'admin' => true));

// search
Router::connect('/search', array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'search'));

// pages
Router::connect('/page/site-map', array('controller' => 'site', 'action' => 'map'));
Router::connect('/page/home', array('controller' => 'site', 'action' => 'home'));
Router::connect('/page/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'));
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? Also, did you clear your caches / restart your webserver after modifying the routes?

Comment: According to cake/VERSION.txt it's version 1.3.2. I read that Router::redirect was only added in 2.x, if this is the case perhaps I need to use a different function?

Comment: CakePHP 1.3 indeed does not have that functionality yet. You should just be a able to add a redirect in the `app/webroot/.htaccess` file though. Should do the trick.

Comment: I tried adding `Redirect 301 /page/online-store http://www.oursite.com` to app/webroot/.htaccess but accessing oursite.com/online-store still gives a 404 error. Any ideas?

Comment: `oursite.com/online-store` is not the same as `oursite.com/page/online-store`. Made a typo there or is that your problem? :)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo! To confirm - visiting `oursite.com/page/online-store` still gives a 404 and the exact line in app/webroot/.htaccess is `Redirect 301 /page/online-store http://www.oursite.com`. This isn't a huge deal as I've fixed it for any future emails but it would be nice to fix it if possible.